# Polymorphism and function binding

Tags: c++, binding, polymorphism

For an event system i'm writing i want to bind callbacks to a list of functions.

Here is a basic example of what i want to do:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

class Base {
  public:
    virtual std::string getType() const = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
  protected:
    int some_data;

  public:

    Derived(int some_data): some_data(some_data) {}

    virtual std::string getType() const {
      return "Derived";
    }

    int getData() const {
      return this->some_data;
    }
};

class DerivedTwo : public Base {
  protected:
    double some_data;

  public:

    DerivedTwo(double some_data): some_data(some_data) {}

    virtual std::string getType() const {
      return "DerivedTwo";
    }

    // The type of data is not always the same.
    double getData() const {
      return this->some_data;
    }
};

// The type of member should ALWAYS be Derived but then i can't store it in <callback>
void onDerivedEvent(Base& member) {
  std::cout << member.getType() << std::endl;

  // This is obviously not possible with member being a base class object
  // member.getData();
}

// The type of member should ALWAYS be DerivedTwo but then i can't store it in <callback>
void onDerivedTwoEvent(Base& member) {
  std::cout << member.getType() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::function<void(Base&)> callback;

  callback = std::bind(onDerivedEvent, std::placeholders::_1);
  callback(Derived(2));

  callback = std::bind(onDerivedTwoEvent, std::placeholders::_1);
  callback(DerivedTwo(3.0));

  return 0;
}
```

The only thing i would like to change is that `onCallback()` should take a derived class member as argument instead of a reference to a base object, so i can call `getData()` for example.
In this example this would mean:

```cpp
void onCallback(Derived& derived);
```

However, if i do this, i can no longer `bind()` the method to `callback` because the argument types are not matching.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

**// EDIT**
Sorry for the confusion here, i updated the source code with some more specifics and examples to maybe clarify what im doing here.

**Note:**
Since it seems like this is very relevant, here is the specific use case for what i'm trying to do here:
It's part of an event system for an engine i'm building. There are basic events pre-defined but it should be extendable with more specific events by a user using this engine. So there is not definitive list of derived classes. Then some object can subscribe to a specific event type and whenever the central event bus recieves such an event, it calls all subscribed callback functions with the event as argument. The reason i am not adding a one and for all handle function in the derived class is, the events an be used in multiple ways.

**Answers to some questions from the comments:**

> What should happen if you pass onCallback an object that isn't that specific Derived&? (ie, add a Derived2 which has a doStuff2. Pass it to callback. What do you want to happen?
>   That should not be possible.

I might have not calrified that and also had a misleading information at the beginning which i have editted since then. The type of the passed derived class is always known beforehand. For example: `onKeyEvent` will always recieve a KeyEvent object and not a base class object or any other derived variants.
However, the variable to which this function is bound should be able to store functions which accept different derived classes from `Base`

This is my storage for all events:

```cpp
std::map<EventType, std::list<std::function<void(const Event&)>>> listener_map;
```

> Why isn't onCallback a method in Base that Derived overrides

I answered this in a comment. `...The reason i am not adding a one and for all handle function in the derived class is, the events an be used in multiple ways...`
Meaning, i might have an `KeyEvent` which has the data to a key (which key, is it pressed/released/held) and the listening function(s) can use this data for whatever it wants. (Check if some specific key is pressed, chech if any random key is pressed and so on.) Some other events might not have any data at all and just notify a listener that something happened or have multiple sets of data etc.

> Is there, or can there be, a finite, bounded at compile time, central list of all of the types that derive from Base at any point in your code?

In theory yes. During compilation there will be a finite number of Derived classes. However these might be different for the compilation of the library and the compilation of the project using this library.

Comment: Add `doStuff` into the base class so you can call it polymorphically like you do with `getType`.

Comment: `dynamic_cast<Derived&>(member).doStuff()`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Maybe this was not clear from my example, but not all events are going to share the same functions and data, so i can't move it to the base class

Comment: That sounds like a design issue.  With polymorphism, the base class defines the interface, and the derived classes implement it.  Trying to extend it further down the chain is just doing to cause issues.

Comment: If you want an off-the-shelf solution, [Boost Signals2](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/signals2.html) can do the job.  Maybe it's overkill for your project.  (Signals2 is for modern C++, the predecessor Signals was for C++98.)

Comment: @NathanOliver if you have a suggestion for a different approach to this you are welcome, but I thought about this a long time and didn't find a better way for my use case, than having a base Event class for my EventBus to which listeners can subscribe via a callback function and the EventType which they want to be called.

Comment: Looks like you want to use double dispatch. A common solution to this is using the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: @Artyer that seems to work, if i dont find a better solution to this i will consider doing this.

Comment: What should happen if you pass `onCallback` an object that isn't that specific `Derived&`?  (ie, add a `Derived2` which has a `doStuff2`.  Pass it to `callback`.  What do you want to happen?)  Why isn't `onCallback` a method in `Base` that `Derived` overrides?  Is there, or can there be, a finite, bounded at compile time, central list of all of the types that derive from `Base` at any point in your code?

Comment: (Note: I ask these questions because various subsets of answers imply very different solutions.  And some subset of answers ends with "stop using C++ to solve this problem".  So don't ask for the moon, or you'll get "you are using the wrong language"; the turing tar pit is the truth that all languages are equally powerful, but the trap is that sometimes some languages are bad solutions to some problems.)

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont It's part of an event system for an engine i'm building. There are basic events pre-defined but it should be extendable with more specific events by a user using this engine. So there is not definitive list of derived classes. Then some object can subscribe to a specific event type and whenever the central event bus recieves such an event, it calls all subscribed callback functions with the event as argument. The reason i am not adding a one and for all handle function in the derived class is, the events an be used in multiple ways. I hope i could explain this well enough.

Comment: There can be a list of all derived classes even if a user of the library can add one.  That just means that portion of the library has to be recompiled, and cannot be a dynamically linked library.  No, that isn't clear enough, you need to be **less abstract** and talk about **actual events** that are examples of what you want to handle, and how they differ.  For one of many examples, how can "events be used in different ways"; you are called when the event fires.  Stop being vague, be specific.  Again, if your problem is "wave hands, anything can happen" you won't get a good answer.

Comment: In addition, sentences ending in `?` are **questions**.  Answers to questions **matter**.  If you won't answer questions clarifying your problem, then you won't get good answers.  Please go over my first comment and **answer the questions put**.  I personally have **many** different solutions to solve what could be your problem, but you won't answer the questions which determine which is the right one, and I am not interested in randomly guessing what your actual problem is.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I updated my original question with answers to your comments. Also, i added some more specifics in the source code which you might want to look at. No need to be rude in the comments though, i was just trying to answer your questions and didn't look at your comments after you editted them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template<class Base>
struct poly_callback {
  template<class T>
  static poly_callback make( std::function<void(T&)> f ) {
    return { std::function<void(void*)>( [f]( void* ptr ) { f(*static_cast<T*>(static_cast<Base*>(ptr))); }) };
  }
  template<class T>
  poly_callback( void(*pf)(T&) ):poly_callback( make<T>( pf ) ) {}
  poly_callback( poly_callback const& ) = default;
  poly_callback( poly_callback && ) = default;
  void operator()( Base& b ) {
    return type_erased( static_cast<void*>(std::addressof(b)) );
  }
private:
  std::function<void(void*)> type_erased;
  poly_callback( std::function<void(void*)> t ):type_erased(std::move(t)) {}
};
```

A `poly_callback<Event>` can store a callable with signature compatible to `void(Derived&)`, where `Derived` is derived from `Event`.  It must be called with *exactly* an instance of the `Derived&` type or undefined behavior results as it blindly downcasts.

Stop using `std::bind`, it is functionally obsolete.

```
class Base {
  public:
    virtual std::string getType() const = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
  protected:
    int some_data;

  public:

    Derived(int some_data): some_data(some_data) {}

    virtual std::string getType() const {
      return "Derived";
    }

    int getData() const {
      return this->some_data;
    }
};

class DerivedTwo : public Base {
  protected:
    double some_data;

  public:

    DerivedTwo(double some_data): some_data(some_data) {}

    virtual std::string getType() const {
      return "DerivedTwo";
    }

    // The type of data is not always the same.
    double getData() const {
      return this->some_data;
    }
};

// The type of member should ALWAYS be Derived but then i can't store it in <callback>
void onDerivedEvent(Derived& member) {
  std::cout << member.getType() << "\n";
  std::cout << member.getData() << "\n";
}

// The type of member should ALWAYS be DerivedTwo but then i can't store it in <callback>
void onDerivedTwoEvent(DerivedTwo& member) {
  std::cout << member.getType() << "\n";
  std::cout << member.getData() << "\n";
}

struct callbacks {
    std::unordered_map< std::string, std::vector< poly_callback<Base> > > events;
    void invoke( std::string const& name, Base& item ) {
        auto it = events.find(name);
        if (it == events.end())
            return;
        for (auto&& f : it->second)
            f( item );
    }
    template<class Derived>
    void connect( std::string const& name, void(*pf)(Derived&) )
    {
        events[name].push_back( pf );
    }
    template<class Derived>
    void connect_T( std::string const& name, std::function<void(Derived&)> f )
    {
        events[name].push_back( std::move(f) );
    }
};

int main() {
  callbacks cb;
  cb.connect("one", onDerivedEvent );
  cb.connect("two", onDerivedTwoEvent );

  Derived d(7);
  DerivedTwo d2(3.14);

  cb.invoke( "one", d );
  cb.invoke( "two", d2 );

  return 0;
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c3acfa48d73ff0c).

This can be tweaked for safety and usability.  For example, check that the typeid actually matches.

Output is:

```
Derived
7
DerivedTwo
3.14
```

and as you can see, the callback functions take `Derived&` and `DerivedTwo&` objects.

---

In my experience this is a bad plan.

Instead, have a `broadcaster<KeyboardEvent> keyboard;` and don't look up your event registry systems with strings.

A map from string-to-callback only makes sense if there is some way to treat the callbacks uniformly.  And you don't want to treat these callbacks uniformly.  Even if you chose to *store* them uniformly for efficiency sake (useful in ridiculously huge frameworks), I'd want type-safe APIs not a map.

Comment: I understand the concerns regarding using a string as index for the map. I might change the identification to use an integer id or something like that in the future. I'm not sure if having a seperate broadcaster for each event type is a viable option though because it makes adding new event types in a project alot harder.

Comment: The primary reason i used `std::bind` to pass along the callback functions was to be able to also store member functions. Is it possible to also pass member functions to `connect`?

Comment: @DJSchaffner No, integer vs string is same difference.  The problem is the complete lack of static type safety both options result in.  Instead of using std bind, use a lambda that captures the object pointer.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance! After some tinkering with the lambda function i think you forgot to add a `poly_callback` constructor for `std::function<void(T&)>` after adding that i managed to get it to work.

Comment: @DJSchaffner I'd recommend calling `poly_callback<Base>::make<T>` in that case, as a lambda is not a `std::function`.